# You Tube Videos on Blog Site?

Tags: discussion, blog

Since a lot of manufactures post videos of new products, tools and how to's on You Tube should we put some of these on the blog site?  Maybe check what's hot on the tags, or maybe seasonal jobs (like Christmas Lights or spring cleaning) and match these up with videos from the manufacturer.

[Eaton - Cutler Hammer Arc Fault Circuit Breakers](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uqZfuRDNz04)

[Klein Tools Hook Meter](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VeocfeDvUXk&list=PL8F140C2B4025E701&feature=plcp&context=C3ee82feFDOEgsToPDskJkkO6Xz-1uf_qb-dHgJfYh)

[Cooper Lighting Halo All Pro Lighting](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X759hET38jw&context=C3bdcf80ADOEgsToPDskKb1nBLJYrthY8lWJ0TLmFW)

I'm sure we have  a lot of trades that we can use.  I think that the videos should be kept to product contributed by a manufacturer or a representative that makes them for the manufacturer, like ElectriSmarts in the electrical trade.  I don't think an individuals video should be put on the blogsite, unless they are a member that contributes to the website.

Comment: That hook meter looks nice! magnet and flashlight, genius!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they fit the entry, sure we can add youtube videos.  As far as using specific manufacturer's videos, it really depends on the point of the entry.  If a contributor writes a review on the Klein Tools Hook Meter (which I am adding to my wishlist), then a manufacturer's video may be appropriate.  My main concern there is to ensure the video fits within the review and isn't just a sales pitch.  On the other hand, we don't want to write a How-To on recessed lighting and highlight just Cooper's video.  Since we're very wary about [promotion and advertising](https://diy.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion) we want the blog to be as uncommercialized as possible.

If anyone would like to volunteer a review please let the blog team know.  We're always looking for contributions.  We hang out in the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1481/diy-blog-contributors) [rooms](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111/home-improvement), you can always leave a message there.  You can create a meta question (like this).  Or if you prefer email, any and all suggestions welcome at **blog.diy.se [at] gmail.com**.